# Always On Location Not Being Requested

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm asking this because I'm a bit confused. I did set `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in my `Info.plist` and this is the code I'm running:

```
CLLocationManager *locMan = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locMan.delegate = self;
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways)
{
    [locMan requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[locMan startUpdatingLocation];
```

I set a breakpoint and verified that this does indeed get  called, but I am not alerted in the app. I check in my privacy settings and saw the app had an entry with the two options: None and Always, with neither checked. I tried to uninstall, clean, and reinstall, but still is not working. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I moved the above block from `viewDidLoad` into `viewDidAppear:` and now the alert comes up and disappears half a second later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. It's a retain issue. I was declaring my `CLLocationManager` locally, so when it reached the end of my method, it would didn't exist anymore, which explains why it couldn't ask for permission. I promoted it to be a property and now all works well

Answer (score 0):

What about if you try this:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;

if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Sorry, missread your post. Maybe try this:

```
CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    // Show alert or something
}
else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

More can be read here: [Core Location Manager Changes in iOS 8](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line at the end of your code

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```